# Send multiple forms data on one page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have multiple forms on one web page. I need that user could post data from any form and this data must send to my email. Now working only 1st form.

HTML:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email">
    </div> 
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr>
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email">
    </div> 
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr>
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email">
    </div> 
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php   
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'my@email.com'; 
$email_subject = "Email from $name";
$email_body = "     Details:\n\n"."
                    Name: $name\n\n
                    Email: $email\n\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"; 

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;    
?>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    $("input").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input.name").val();
            var email = $("input.email").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

What should I change? How can I submit all 3 forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single form like:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" class="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email" class="email">
    </div> 
<div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" class="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email" class="email">
    </div> 

    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {

$("input").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input.name").val();
        var email = $("input.email").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});});
/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all button types from `submit` to `button` and add an onClick event to call function, that is

`<input type "button" onclick="savedata()" />`

and the function will be like this:

`<script>
 function savedata()
 {
    .... your ajax request here....
 }
 </script>`